# how group values into smaller sets of values in a data set?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

basically I have a single column data set of 53 values. what I am trying to achieve is binning them into sets based on a 400 point difference, ranging from ~500 to 4500. you can just be vague if needed and state a function for doing so, I can work out the rest

Comment: Hi @Jonah_huggins. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, visit this thread on how to make a great R reproducible example. Could you provide a `dput()`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` option

```
library(dplyr)
df_test <- data.frame(x = runif(1000, 400, 5000),
                      y = rep("A", 1000))

df_test <- df_test %>% 
  mutate(bins = case_when(between(x, 400, 800) ~ "Set 1",
                          between(x, 801, 1600) ~ "Set 2",
                          between(x, 1601, 5000) ~ "Set 3"))
head(df_test)
              x y  bins
    1 1687.2854 A Set 3
    2 3454.1035 A Set 3
    3 4979.5434 A Set 3
    4  796.6475 A Set 1
    5 3665.7444 A Set 3
    6 3083.8969 A Set 3
```

You can of course adjust the `between` ranges as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach that uses `cut` with `breaks =` defined with a predetermined `seq`.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- runif(n=53,500,4500)
groups <- as.integer(cut(data,c(-Inf,seq(500,4500,by=400),Inf))) 
data.frame(data,groups)
      data groups
1 1562.035      4
2 1988.496      5
3 2791.413      7
4 4132.831     11
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for responding with this, however I would love to ask you a following question: I read up on cut() and used: signals.2 <- cut(as.numeric(as.character(data$Beta.Actin.Signals)), breaks = seq(0, 4500, by = 500)) however when displaying the plot, this omits any points that come up as 0, as in out of the 11 bins I wish to create, any bin that is empty is not displayed on the graph, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i would do it like this:

```
data$group<-cut(data$value,
               breaks = seq(0,4500,500),
               labels = paste("Group",LETTERS[1:9], sep="_"))
```

or if you prefer more basic style of R use [ ] :

```
under_500<-data[data$value<500 ,]

over500_under900<-data[data$value %in% 501:900 ,]
## etc..
over4000<-data[data$value>4000 ,]
```